# Shrinkwrap modifier not displaying correctly in edit mode when the target object has a subsurface division modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, shrinkwrap

When I am in edit mode on the target object of a shrinkwrap modifier, the shrinkwrapped objects do not show their shrinkwrapped positions, and instead revert to their default position, which makes adjustments trial and error.

Toggling "View in edit mode" on any of the modifiers does not keep the shrinkwrap visible in edit mode while editing the target object. Is this possible?

EDIT: The trouble seems to happen when a subsurface modifier is on the target object, and entering edit mode on the target object causes the shrinkwrap modifier to shrinkwrap to the object BEFORE the subsurface modifier has been applied.

EDIT 2: Inexplicably, this bug seems to be dependent on the computer that is running blender. On certain desktops, it displays correctly in edit mode, and on others, it does not. If anyone has insight into this it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 3: I have discovered a workaround after coming across this vaguely related sculpt mode bug report (https://developer.blender.org/T95761). If a mirror modifier is placed AFTER the subsurface division modifier on the target object, the shrinkwrap will display correctly in edit mode. A redundant, second mirror modifier can be placed at the bottom of a modifier stack to serve this purpose.

Blendfile: [image]

Object Mode:
[image]

Edit Mode:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the underlying reason for this bug is currently unknown, a workaround has been found:

If a mirror modifier is placed AFTER the subsurface division modifier on the target object, the shrinkwrap will display correctly in edit mode. A redundant, second mirror modifier can be placed at the bottom of a modifier stack to serve this purpose.

This workaround is also referenced in this sculpt mode bug report (https://developer.blender.org/T95761).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to BSE,

I tried to recreate your issue by applying a Shrinkwrap modifier to a subdivided plane, using a Monkey head as the Target object:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can edit the Monkey Head (target) object, and the Shrinkwrap modifier on the Plane object updates in real time:

[image]

Maybe I've missed understood your issue?

If not, please make sure that when you are editing your target object, **only** the target object is selected.
It is possible that you have both the target object **and** the object with the Shrinkwrap modifier selected. If so, when you enter Edit mode, you are entering Edit Mode for **both** objects.

When you enter Edit mode for the object with the Shrinkwrap modifier applied, the modifier is temporarily disabled.

If nothing else works, I'd suggest deleting the current Shrinkwrap modifier and adding a fresh one.

Edit (as per comment):

In this example I've added a Subdivision Surface Modifier to the target object, but I'm still not seeing any issues with the Shrinkwrap Modifier:

[image]

[image]

Edit 2 (As per comment):

I've downloaded your .blend file and opened it. Without making any changes whatsoever, I selected the Suzanne head, and started pressing Tab to switch between Object and Edit mode. I couldn't see the same issue from your screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I tried in both Blender 3.2 and Blender 3.4.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and investigation. I am now aware that the interaction I am describing is occurring because a subsurface modifier is also being used on the target object. Is this unavoidable?

Comment: You're welcome :) I've added some screenshots to the bottom of my answer including a Subdiv, but I'm afraid I'm still not seeing your issue. Maybe you could edit your question and add some screenshots to demo the issue?

Comment: You're certain you are not accidentally editing both objects? While in Object Mode, press ALT+A to DEselect everything, then left-click the Target Object to make sure it is the ONLY object selected when you enter Edit mode. As mentioned in my answer, if you accidentally have the Shrinkwrap Object selected when you enter Edit mode, the Shrinkwrap modifier will be temporarily deactivated.

Comment: I've added a couple screenshots showing the difference between edit and object mode on suzanne.

Comment: Interesting... I've tried to recreate the problem as per your screenshots but have been unable to. Would you mind sharing your .blend file? https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: Mysterious! Blend file added to post.

Comment: Even more mysterious - I tried opening your file in both Blender 3.2 and 3.4 and STILL couldn't recreate the problem! (See screenshots added to my answer)

Comment: Well. Isn't that splendid. haha. Hm. Not sure... what to make of this. Very bizarre and troublesome. Regardless, thank you again for your persistent efforts to try and solve this with me!

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't solve it. As a last ditch option, you could try 1) remove the Subsurf and Shrinkwrap modifiers, and save your project. 2) Open a new project. 3) Use File > Append to browse to your saved project and add the Shrinkwrap and Target objects into your new project. 4) Add the Shrinkwrap and Subsurf modifiers. I'd be curious if you still have the problem in this case.

Comment: I'm baffled. This behavior persists when creating new blend files and repeating the steps. Updated from blender 3.2.1 to 3.2.2 and the problem still persists. What could we possibly try and rule out that could be causing this to occur in my blender but not yours?

Comment: Also I should note, I have tested this on another desktop here, and the behavior is persistent between the two computers I've tested it on. Same behavior on both.

Comment: I tested this on a 3rd desktop, and on the 3rd desktop, blender functions as it does on your end SlickRed. Haven't a clue what the difference between the systems is. Perplexed.

Comment: That is so strange. I'm glad you were able to at least prove that I haven't lost my mind, and that there IS in fact a difference in behaviour between our 2 machines, but I have no idea what could be causing it.

Comment: Wow I found a workaround from a vaguely related sculpt mode bug report (https://developer.blender.org/T95761) that is marked as a "Known Issue". If a mirror modifier is placed AFTER the subsurface division (even if there is another mirror modifier happening before the subsurface division), the shrinkwrap will operate the correct way in edit mode.

Do you think this is useful information to share in some other place other than this stack exchange?

Comment: I think what you should do is answer your own question with this work-around information :) It may be useful to someone else who is experiencing the same problem.

Comment: If you wanted to upvote my answer as helpful (though it did not resolve your issue), I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Good thinking! I have upvoted your answer (which should hopefully show up when I have reached 15 reputation? I guess?). Thanks again for helping me look into this. Very much appreciated my friend.

Comment: Any time :) All the best